# Format Nhibernate SQL Logs in MSTest Output

Tags: nhibernate, mstest, logging

How to format sql logs from nhibernate written in MSTest Standard Console output?

I already set

Configuration.DatabaseIntergation Properties like

```
db.LogInConsole = true;
db.LogFormattedSql = true;
db.AutoCommentSql = true;
```

but the output in the test result is still ugly.

Comment: what is still ugly? Do you see any difference between LogFormatted = true and = false? AFAIK LogFormattedSql only inserts line breaks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NHibernate only inserts "\n" as a line break but Visual Studio only shows line breaks that are "\r\n". If you view the test result file (it's just an XML file) in any good text editor you'll see the line breaks.

I don't think that you can change NHibernate without recombiling it but it's really more a problem of Visual Studio than of NHibernate.